# Biased coin check

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How many trials are needed to decide with 50% confidence that a coin is biased?

I suspect there is some missing information. Any ideas / pointers?

Comment: I would assume you would need to specify the level of bias.

Comment: can't we use the info that p(H)  is not equal to 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  a "hypothesis testing" problem of roughly standard shape. However, the figure of $50\%$ makes no practical sense at all in this context.

We have the *null hypothesis* $H_0$ that says the coin is unbiased, and the *alternate hypothesis* $H_1$ that says the coin is biased. The test is two-sided, since the alternate hypothesis makes no reference to the direction of the bias.

Suppose that we toss the coin $n$ times. We will reject the null hypothesis in favour of the alternate hypothesis if, **assuming** the coin is fair, the proportion of heads we got would happen less than $50\%$ of the time.

Let $n=2$ and suppose that we reject the null hypothesis if we get $2$ heads or $2$ tails. With a fair coin, this would happen exactly $50\%$ of the time. So perhaps $n=2$ is the intended answer. However, a more sensible answer (to a quite unreasonable question) is to take $n=3$, and to reject the null hypothesis if we get $3$ heads or $3$ tails. Then, when the null hypothesis is true, we will reject it with probability $\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}$, which is **under** $50\%$.

**Remark:** Traditionally, one rejects the null hypothesis $H_0$ in favour of $H_1$ if, on the hypothesis that $H_0$ is true, the experimental result has probability $\lt 5\%$ of happening. Or else one may use the more stringent $1\%$ criterion. The figure of $50\%$ makes no practical sense: obviously one would not reject the hypothsis that a coin is fair if we got $3$ heads or $3$ tails.

Comment: thanks, I cannot vote up due to restrictions. Can we also think like the following? If we are 50% confident the coin is biased, then we are also 50% confident that it is not. This means that for p(Heads)=0.5, we can use CI = 1.96*sqrt(p*(1-p)/N) where N is the desired number of trials.

Comment: We cannot. The $1.96$ applies when (i) the sample size is large enough for a normal approximation to be sensible and (ii) the level of significance is $5\%$. In the question you were asked, the significance level is the ridiculous $50\%$. I think the question is a "conceptual" question to test your understanding of significance level.

Comment: I have been thinking of the multinomial case and by assuming a more reasonable confidence. E.g. how many trials are needed to decide with 95% confidence that a die is loaded. Still the CI formulation would not be useful I guess, since I am confident that the die is loaded but I do not have the multinomial distribution probabilities at hand.

Comment: In a real problem, a fair amount of care and practical knowledge is rquired to formulate the right $H_0$, $H_1$. In the die situation, a suitable simple $H_0$ might be that the probability of a $6$ is $1/6$, a simple binomial situation. There are extensions of simple hypothesis testing to multivariate settings, never dealt with in first courses.

Comment: Among simpler general purpose multivariate tests, you may want to look up chi-square.